# Is there a way to see spots on a model that don't have any weight painting on them?

Tags: bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

I'm trying to get my model's head to pose correctly but when I try to pose it, some of the face (eyes) stays in one spot.

Here's the blender file:

[image]

[image: Head up]
Head up

[image: Head to side]
Head to side

[image: Head normal]
Head normal

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files. Files on other services tend to "vanish", thus rendering your question and possible answers practically useless in the future. Please use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135101/edit) below your question to edit your post. Also, [adding images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/23985) would help us a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you for informing me of blender-exchange. I have updated the post with pictures as well as the blender-exchange link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was, the "neck" vertex group had some weight painting from the "head" vertex group. All I had to do was select the "neck" vertex group and subtract from it.